# Iterating Text in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to iterate through a `Text` and print its contents. This is the code I tried:

```
    Text text = new Text();
    text.set("Hadoop");
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes(),0,text.getLength());
    int cp = 0;
    while(buf.hasRemaining() && (cp = Text.bytesToCodePoint(buf)) != 1)
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(cp));
```

This is printing me the code points. How to print the characters from this?

**EDIT**

For the input "Hadoop", casting the `int cp` to a `char` inside your while loop works. BUT, when the text is something like `\u0041\u00DF\u6771\uD801\uDC00` then using the same code I am getting a `couple of ?` printed in the console. Any specific reasons for this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be for you to just cast your `ints` to `chars`. Like so:

```
int[] chars = { 0x41, 0xdf, 0x6671, 0x10400 };
for(int c : chars) {
    String out = String.format("%d -> %s", c, (char) c);
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

My output is:

```
65 -> A
223 -> ß
26225 -> 晱
66560 -> Ѐ
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am unable to understand ow can I fit this code in the code that I posted. Please advice.

Comment: Just cast your `int cp` to a char inside your while loop.